# How does control flow work when retrieving Information from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
var ergebnisBluetezeit = Set<String>()

let refBluetezeit = rootRef.child("Pflanzen").child("Eigenschaften").child("Blütezeit")
    refBluetezeit.child("Februar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                    for plant in snapshot.children {
                        self.ergebnisBluetezeit.insert((plant as AnyObject).value)
                    }
                })
    print(ergebnisBluetezeit)
```

I want to retrieve Data from my Firebase Database. The Retrieving Process does work already, but the following confuses me: the current output from the print is an empty set, but when i use the var ergebnisBluetezeit elsewhere (for example setup a button, which action is to print ergebnisBluetezeit), it is filled. When i put the print in the for loop, it does print the right output, too. 
I seem to not have understood the control flow here, so my Question: 
How can i use the Set where the print statement is at the moment?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the logic of asynchronous calls

```
print("1") // empty
refBluetezeit.child("Februar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in     

 print("3") // empty
 for plant in snapshot.children {
         self.ergebnisBluetezeit.insert((plant as AnyObject).value)
  }
    print(ergebnisBluetezeit) // not empty
})

print("2") // empty
```

the value is empty until the request finishes regardless of where in code ordering you run the print  , as the numbering above in order 1 , 2 , 3 to know when it finishes you can use completions like

```
func getData(completion:@escaping() -> ()) {
    let refBluetezeit = rootRef.child("Pflanzen").child("Eigenschaften").child("Blütezeit")
    refBluetezeit.child("Februar").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for plant in snapshot.children {
            self.ergebnisBluetezeit.insert((plant as AnyObject).value)
        }
        completion()
    })
}
```

And call

```
getData {
   print(ergebnisBluetezeit)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Sounds good to me. I guess it doesnt make sense for me to use this in my scenario. I got like 10 categories, which "Blütezeit" (heyday) is just one of. for each category, there are around 10 of these calls. Obviously, it would be much slower if the program waited for each retrieval to complete before it starts the next one. After all the retrieval, a new view pops up, where the information is displayed, but it has to be ordered und filtered first. Do you know an option to start these 10 methods without waiting for each other, but continuing when all are finished?

Comment: i guess you need to structure the database properly or listen to an outer root that contains all categories , for you current request you can google `DispatchGroup` http://jordansmith.io/dispatch-groups-in-swift-3/